# Shell script to login to ubuntu server and then process commands

Tags: shell, unix

I have a shell script(.sh file) which logs in to ubuntu server using ssh command. Once logged in i want to do the following commands:

```
sudo -i
su web
```

I want to incorporate the above commands in the same .sh file. How do i do it? Thanks

Comment: what is your ultimate goal? sudo to web user sounds very security risky

Comment: Check the `sudo` full path `SUDO=which sudo` and then add `$SUDO -i; su web` in your code?

Comment: @mvp My ultimate goal is, when the .sh file is run, i should be logged in to the ubuntu server, change my user to web user and then cd to a particular folder. Curently, i have to run multiple commands to achieve the same. I want to achieve it in a single command

Comment: ok, but you are not going to be there, it will be impersonated, right? You will not be able to get a hold of this automatically established invisible session. My question is what is it do you really want to do as a result of executing all of this? Because I suspect you have better, faster and more secure way to get the job done.

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo -u key -i`?